# CXF-Client generation fails with referenced Type can not be found in the schemas

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate a client from a wsdl with apache cxf. But it fails with the message:

```
Part <request> in Message <{[...]/wsdl}[...]auftrag> referenced Type <{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}any> can not be found in the schemas
```

From the wsdl:

```
    <wsdl:operation name="[...]">
      <wsdl:input message="nass:[...]auftrag"/>
      <wsdl:output message="nass:[...]ergebnis"/>
      <wsdl:fault name="exception" message="xs:any"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

I tried to change the message type to something else, but it doesn't work.

I am using apache cxf 3.6.2.